# Add,remove and remove All methods in array without using any other data structure or any other imports

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a sorted array and some methods to do different functions. The problem is that my assignment has various methods and i have implement those methods using the test file to check.The condition of the assignment is that i cannot import anything and i have to use just what's available in the program

I tried to do it and also did the research but i am unable to figure it out.Using Array List,it becomes very straight forward,but it will not help.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SortedArray<T extends Comparable> implements java.lang.Iterable<T> {

/** Constructor: constructs and empty OrderedArray with an initial capacity
 * as given.
 * 
 * Complexity: the time complexity of this operation must be O(1).
 * 
 * @param capacity initial capacity
 */


public SortedArray(int capacity) {

this.array = (T[]) new Comparable[0];
this.capacity = capacity;
this.size = 0;


}

/** Constructs an ordered array from an (unordered) array. The
 * initial capacity of the array should either be capacity, or the size of
 * data, whichever is larger.
 * 
 * Complexity: the time complexity of this operation must be O(n^2) in the 
 * size of data.
 * 
 * @param capacity initial capacity of the array
 * @param data elements to populate the array with
 */
public SortedArray(int capacity, T[] data) {


    if(capacity > data.length)
    {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    else {
            this.capacity = data.length;
            }
    this.size = data.length;

    this.array = (T[]) new Comparable[0];

}


/** Returns the current size of the array (number of elements 
 * inserted, minus number of elements removed).
 * 
 * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(1).
 * 
 * @return Size of the array  
 */
final public int size() {      

    return this.size;

    }

/** Returns the capacity (maximum size) of the array.
 * 
 * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(1).
 * 
 * @return Capacity of the array
 */
final public int capacity() {


    return this.capacity;
}

/** Returns true if the array is empty (size is 0).
 * 
 * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(1).
 * 
 * @return true if the array is empty
 */
final boolean isEmpty() {


        return array.length == 0;

}

/** Returns true if the array is full (size = capacity).
 * 
 * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(1).
 * 
 * @return true if the array is full
 */
final boolean isFull() {


        return size == capacity;

}

/** Adds an element to the array, by inserting it at the proper
 * location. Note that duplicate elements can be added.
 * 
 * If the array is full(), nothing should be inserted, and the array's
 * contents should be unchanged.
 * 
 * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(n) in the size()
 * of the array.
 * 
 * @param element to be added
 */


final void add(T element) {

    if(this.array.length != this.capacity){
           this.indexOf(element);
    }

    Arrays.sort(this.array);


}



/** Removes the specified element from the array, if it
 * exists. If the element does not exist, does nothing.
 * 
 * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(n) in the size
 * of the array.
 * 
 * @param element to be removed 
 * 
 */
final void remove(T element) {


   for(int i =0; i<this.size;i++){
       if(this.array[i] == element)
           this.indexOf(element);
    }
}      




/** Removes all elements from the array.
 */
final void clear() {


    this.clear();


}


@Override
final public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    // Do not modify this method.
    return Arrays.stream(array).iterator();
}

// Do not modify these data members.
final private T[] array;     // Storage for the array's element
private int size;      // Current size of the array
final private int capacity;  // Maximum size of the array

 }
```

The results I am getting is that my tests are failing, but the constructor and capacity test works.Just don't know why the other methods are failing as methods like size,isFull and isEmpty seems pretty simple.Hope,someone can explain the problems thoroughly.And also a way to perform add and remove operations by just using Arrays.Also,want to know what things i am doing wrong

Comment: extend the `ArrayList` and modify all the methods you want different from a usual ArrayList

Comment: You haven't implemented sorting in the second constructor. Also, where is this indexOf() method?

Comment: instead of creating array of Type T `T[]`. use ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

In the first constructor, the size of the array should be the capacity. Not 0.
In the second constructor, your data is never copied into the array.
The second constructor asks for O(n^2) so you can use the built in sorting of `Arrays.sort` which is O(n*log(n)).
Adding and removing an element must be in in O(n), so you can't use `Arrays.sort`. Just step over each element until you find the correct index. Copy data where needed.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class SortedArray<T extends Comparable> implements java.lang.Iterable<T> {

    /**
     * Constructor: constructs and empty OrderedArray with an initial capacity
     * as given.
     * <p>
     * Complexity: the time complexity of this operation must be O(1).
     *
     * @param capacity initial capacity
     */
    public SortedArray(int capacity) {
        if (capacity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        this.array = (T[]) new Comparable[capacity];
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an ordered array from an (unordered) array. The
     * initial capacity of the array should either be capacity, or the size of
     * data, whichever is larger.
     * <p>
     * Complexity: the time complexity of this operation must be O(n^2) in the
     * size of data.
     *
     * @param capacity initial capacity of the array
     * @param data     elements to populate the array with
     */
    public SortedArray(int capacity, T[] data) {
        if (capacity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (capacity > data.length) {
            this.capacity = capacity;
        } else {
            this.capacity = data.length;
        }
        this.size = data.length;

        this.array = Arrays.copyOf(data, this.size);
        Arrays.sort(this.array);
    }


    /**
     * Returns the current size of the array (number of elements
     * inserted, minus number of elements removed).
     * <p>
     * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(1).
     *
     * @return Size of the array
     */
    final public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the capacity (maximum size) of the array.
     * <p>
     * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(1).
     *
     * @return Capacity of the array
     */
    final public int capacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the array is empty (size is 0).
     * <p>
     * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(1).
     *
     * @return true if the array is empty
     */
    final boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the array is full (size = capacity).
     * <p>
     * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(1).
     *
     * @return true if the array is full
     */
    final boolean isFull() {
        return size == capacity;
    }

    /**
     * Adds an element to the array, by inserting it at the proper
     * location. Note that duplicate elements can be added.
     * <p>
     * If the array is full(), nothing should be inserted, and the array's
     * contents should be unchanged.
     * <p>
     * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(n) in the size()
     * of the array.
     *
     * @param element to be added
     */
    final void add(T element) {
        if (isFull()) {
            return;
        }
        if (element == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        int insertAt = 0;
        for (; insertAt < size; insertAt++) {
            if (element.compareTo(array[insertAt]) < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (size - 1 - insertAt >= 0) {
            System.arraycopy(array, insertAt, array, insertAt + 1, size - insertAt);
        }
        array[insertAt] = element;
        size++;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified element from the array, if it
     * exists. If the element does not exist, does nothing.
     * <p>
     * Complexity: the time complexity of this method must be O(n) in the size
     * of the array.
     *
     * @param element to be removed
     */
    final void remove(T element) {
        if (isEmpty() || element == null) {
            return;
        }

        int removeAt = 0;
        for (; removeAt < size; removeAt++) {
            if (array[removeAt].compareTo(element) == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (removeAt < size) {
            System.arraycopy(array, removeAt + 1, array, removeAt, size - removeAt - 1);
            array[size - 1] = null;
            size--;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Removes all elements from the array.
     */
    final void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    final public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // Do not modify this method.
        return Arrays.stream(array).iterator();
    }

    // Do not modify these data members.
    final private T[] array;     // Storage for the array's element
    private int size;      // Current size of the array
    final private int capacity;  // Maximum size of the array
}
```